# Campos de tabla mysql en una columna

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta donde hago `inner join` de varias tablas:

```
select a.precio, sum(m.coste) as coste_mantenimiento, sum(r.coste) as coste_revision from inv_articulo as a
inner join inv_mantenimiento_equipo as m on a.pk_articulo = m.fk_equipo
inner join inv_revision as r on a.pk_articulo = r.fk_articulo
where a.pk_articulo = 1;
```

El resultado que me devuelve es el sigueinte:

```
    precio    |   coste_mantenimiento    |   coste_revision
---------------------------------------------------------------
     52.00              104.00                     56.00
```

¿Cómo podría montar la consulta para que los resultados quedasen así?

```
    definicion    |    coste
----------------------------------
      precio           52.00
    coste_mant         104.00
    coste_rev          56.00
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes conseguirlo con `UNION` y varios `SELECTS`, uno por fila a mostrar.

Ejemplo:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INT,
  id_art INT,
  coste1 INT
);
INSERT INTO table1 (id, id_art, coste1) VALUES (1,1,10);
INSERT INTO table1 (id, id_art, coste1) VALUES (2,1,20);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id INT,
  id_art INT,
  coste2 INT
);
INSERT INTO table2 (id, id_art, coste2) VALUES (1,1,30);
INSERT INTO table2 (id, id_art, coste2) VALUES (2,1,40);

CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id INT,
  id_art INT,
  coste3 INT
);
INSERT INTO table3 (id, id_art, coste3) VALUES (1,1,50);
INSERT INTO table3 (id, id_art, coste3) VALUES (2,1,60);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT SUM(t1.coste1) AS coste FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id_art=1
UNION 
SELECT SUM(t2.coste2) AS coste FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_art=1
UNION 
SELECT SUM(t3.coste3) AS coste FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.id_art=1
;

| coste |
| ----- |
| 30    |
| 70    |
| 110   |
```

---

**EDICIÓN para añadir una columna con nombres**

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 'nombre1' AS nombre, SUM(t1.coste1) AS coste FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id_art=1
UNION 
SELECT 'nombre2' AS nombre,SUM(t2.coste2) AS coste FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_art=1
UNION 
SELECT 'nombre3' AS nombre,SUM(t3.coste3) AS coste FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.id_art=1
;

| nombre  | coste |
| ------- | ----- |
| nombre1 | 30    |
| nombre2 | 70    |
| nombre3 | 110   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: como podría con tu función añadirle una columna con los nombres de cada coste?? Para que quede como en mi ejemplo

Comment: @Maginon edito la respuesta para añadir una columna de nombres

Comment: Perfecto! Me sirvió! Muchisimas gracias!